# How to switch fragment from with cardview click

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to change the current fragment to another fragment by clicking a cardview in the current fragment. I have this method in my main activity for switching fragments when a list is clicked and it works fine

```
private void ListItemClicked(int position)
{
    Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            fragment = Fragment1.NewInstance();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = Fragment2.NewInstance();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = radio.NewInstance();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = month1.NewInstance();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = Fragment2.NewInstance();
            break;
    }
    SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment).Commit();
}
```

Now I am tried this in my fragment

```
MyCardView.Click += delegate {
    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity;
    activity.ListItemClicked(2);
};
```

But it gives an activity destroyed error

Please any ideas on how to go to any fragment in an application, not just those managed by fragment manager in `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `MainActivity` class and trying to invoke `ListItemClicked` method on that. This is causing the error. You should grab an instance of the Activity that hosts this fragment and then invoke the method. Like below,

```
MyCardView.Click += delegate {
((MainActivity)Activity).ListItemClicked(2);
};
```

But for doing so you will need to declare your `ListItemClicked` method as `public` so that it can be accessed from other classes. SO you will have to change the definition to

```
public void ListItemClicked(int position)
{
}
```

Comment: Will this cause the fragments to change?

Comment: Yes, It will invoke the ListItemClicked method definded in the parent Activity and cause  radio fragment to be loaded as per your code.